# Connecting apple watch to parse notifications?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I want my parse notifications to show on the apple watch, and simply open the app on the iPhone when the okay button is tapped. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According apple:
"When one of your app’s local or remote notifications arrives on the user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on the Apple Watch."
So, you can't ensure that notification will be received on the watch.
Also, in case the notification is received on the applewatch, it is not possible to open the iPhone by pressing a Button (or anything). It does not exist such a method for that. The only way to open the app is manually.

Comment: I believe you can decide to take an action which can then be executed in code. But you can't actually open the app. For instance "Reply: Yes" or "Reply: No" etc...